# switching from vc6 to mingw

Tags: dll, mingw

Two (quite old) libraries are written in C and originally compiled with MSVC 6. I want to change this and start using this with mingw.

Edit: the library looks to be using __stdcall calling convention.

So library 'a' is built first and a.lib and a.dll are produced including a.def by MSVC 6. Then library b is built and it uses library: a.lib.

I succeeded building a.dll with mingw. But I don't know how to build a.lib file ? Another requirement is that I need to do this entirely with MinGW tools or some other (free) solution.

Another question is will mingw libraries mix and match with msvc if we assume code is entirely done in C language? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that MinGW can do that MSVC can't do is link directly to DLLs - in other words, MinGW doesn't need an import library.  Just pass the DLL as an input to the MinGW linker and that should be as good as using an import library.

In general, C language DLL exports should be usable by either MSVC or MinGW regardless of which tool created them.  However there are corner cases which might not work correctly. Off the top of my head there are some differences in the ABI in how structures are returned and there might be some differences in how some floating point types are handled.  Most DLL APIs that I've ever come across don't do either of these things, but there may be other corner cases I'm not thinking or aware of.